# Freeswitch: Can't do video call/conference using H26x

Tags: linux, video, codec

I using FS 1.6 . I've compiled it source codes. There is no problem when doing a video call using `VP8` codec, but when I restrict the clients to use `H263` or `H264` codecs, no video is shown. After investigating FS logs and network packets, i found out that clients request `H263` or `H264` but FS does not negotiate it!

Following lines show that FS only compare `H264` with `VP8`:

```
2017-01-25 05:58:07.132032 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4843 Video Codec Compare [H264:108]/[VP8:99]
2017-01-25 05:58:07.132032 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4843 Video Codec Compare [H264:99]/[VP8:99]
```

Although  `H264` is loaded as `show codec` output in `fs_cli` is:

```
...
codec,GSM,mod_spandsp
codec,H.261 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263+ Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263++ Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.264 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
...
codec,VP8 Video,CORE_VPX_MODULE
codec,VP9 Video,CORE_VPX_MODULE

30 total.
```

This problem occurs in video conference call and point to point call.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add H264 in /etc/freeswitch/vars.xml?
At this line:

Video has not worked for me while having both VP8 and H264 configured in this line so you might have to stick to only VP8 or H264.